# Use product rule and mathematical induction to show that $f^n$ is differentiable on $I$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, induction

Suppose that $f$ is differentiable on $I$. Use the product rule and mathematical induction to show that $f^n$ (the function f is raised to the nth power) is differentiable on $I$ for every positive integer $n$ and find a formula for $(f^n)’$.

Comment: This is only true for $C^\infty$ functions.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @Git Gud: Perhaps $f^n$ means her : $f \times \cdots \times f$, $n$ times. Does'nt it ?

Comment: @Mohamed Makes sense.

Comment: @Git Gud: I think the questioner should clarify that it was real-valued function and explain the $f^n$ notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think other replies to this thread are confused about what the question is asking. The question is not asking to prove that $f^{(n)}$ is differentiable, it is asking to prove that $f^n$ (the $n^{th}$ power of $f$) is differentiable.

We'll use strong induction to show that $(f^n)' = nf^{n-1}f'$.

Consider the base case, $n=1$. $f^1 = f$ is differentiable by assumption of the problem, and the formula for its derivative is given by $f' = 1f^{1-1} f'$ because $f^{1-1} = 1$. So clearly our property holds.

Now we'll assume that $f^i$ is differentiable for any $i < n$ and its derivative moreover is given by $(f^i)' = if^{i-1}f'$ and we'll prove the same holds for $f^{n}$. We note that $f^{n} = f^{n-1} f$. From here, we can invoke the $i=2$ case (which is simply a statement of the product rule) to get that $f^n$ is differentiable. We can also use the $i=2, i=1$, and $i = n-1$ cases to get that $$(f^{n})' = [f^{n-1} f]' = (f^{n-1})'f + f' f^{n-1} = (n-1)f^{n-2}f'f + f'f^{n-1} = (n-1)f^{n-1}f' + f^{n-1}f' = nf^{n-1}f'$$ which is the formula we posited. So in particular, for every natural number $n$, we've proved by strong induction that $$(f^n)' = nf^{n-1}f'.$$

Comment: It's a little odd that you do the base case for $n=1$, but then use the case $n=2$ implicitly with product rule. Perhaps you wanna use strong induction?

Comment: You're right. I just assumed that the poster was allowed to assume the product rule, but it is a little odd that the product rule is in fact the n=2 case. Instead of using strong induction though, I think one could just instead show the n=1 and n=2 cases and then prove the result by normal induction (since n>2 is not used for the induction step).

Comment: I think that's more natural too, but it's easier to adapt your answer to strong induction, hence my suggestion. By the way, I want to upvote you, but i've reached my limit for the day.

Comment: Yah, just for clarity I went ahead and edited my answer per your suggestion. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: No problem. I'll be able to upvote in 10 minutes $\ddot \smile$

Comment: Done. Nice job.

Answer (score 0):

This is false as stated, if by $f^n$ you meant iterated derivative $f$ . Take $f(x)$ with: $$f(x)=-x^2/2$$ if $x\leq 0$ and $$f(x)=x^2/2$$ if $x>0$. Then $f$ is differentiable, but $f'=|x|$ is not.
( Note that if instead of a Real-variable function $f(x)$, you had $f(z)$ as a complex-valued function , then it would be true that $f^n(z)$ , as the $n-th$ derivative always exists--and it is analytic.

EDIT: I read $f^n$ to mean the $n-th$ application of the derivative, but some have poined out that is not what the OP meant. If by $f^n$ you mean n-th product, then you can say that when $f,g$ are differentiable, then $f.g$ is differentiable, and 
$(f.g)'=f'g+fg'$ , so that $f.f$ is differentiable. Then $(f^3)'$=$(f.f^2)'$ is also the product of differentiable functions, and the same applies. Then, using induction,
 $(f^{n+1})'=([(f^n)(f)]'$ is the product of differentiable functions.

Comment: I think that $f^n$ means her : $f^n=f \times f ... \times f$ , $n$  times , not $f^{(n)}$ the $n$ th derivative.

Comment: I think the notation $f^n$ means the $n$-fold product of $f$, not the $n$-th derivative of $f$. In this case, your example is not a counterexample to the original statement.

Comment: O.K, I've edited to cover both cases.